# Importing Data from Audio CD using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, audio-recording

I am doing a music album library.The program should connect to a database like FreeDB and then store it.

At the moment, it is just a concept and I want to know if it is possible to do it. The real question is, Is there a way to get the data from cd like what happens when you play a disc in Windows Media Player? I did a bit of a reasearch and I found about ID3 and mp3 but I don't think it will be any lead as the tracks are .cda.

I am studying programing (diploma). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Window Media Player can do this: Pop in a CD and it will try to retreive the album info (CD name, artist, track names, etc...). *How* it does this, using CDA files, I'm not sure.

Comment: The cda files don't actually contain the music. They are only descriptor files. The audio data itself is usually uncompressed 16 bit PCM at 44100 samples in stereo. But I don't know how to open an audio cd track for reading.

Comment: I read about the cda and not containing the audio itself... interesting to know.

Answer (score 4):

I found a tutorial with sample code that should help you out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/freedb.aspx

Comment: FTA: There are two class libraries included with the demo application.

Freedb - classes for retrieving CD database information from freedb servers. This is the library that I created for this article.

Ripper - this is a modified version of the C Sharp Ripper library. This library is used to access a CD drive and retrieve low level audio CD information. ... I modified the CDDrive class to include a couple of methods for calculating a disc ID and track offsets based on the freedb specifications. This information is used to query the freedb database.

Comment: Thanks. I had already came across that and by far the closest.... I will give a deep read!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write all of the code from scratch you will need to learn about [Red Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Book_%28audio_Compact_Disc_standard%29).  Otherwise you may want to just automate something such as media player.

Comment: not sure what you mean about automation and media player... but i am reading about the red book! thanks.

Comment: what I mean about automation is finding and API to control or script other apps.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on my vague memories of the incomplete description that the team behind that feature in the Windows 98 era provided. The specifics of the implementation were confidential, and I wasn't privy to the details, and things may have changed quite a bit in the ensuing 13 or so years since I first experimented with this feature.

A representative sample of binary data from the CD was read in and converted into some sort of CRC-like checksum or a hash. The checksum was sent to a web service that contained a database matching those checksums to the album information.

When possible, the exact disk was matched; apparently, there were just enough conflicts in my own collection that I was sometimes presented with a list of possible albums.

Microsoft spent a fair amount of money building this database and the data included a partnership with at least one third party company. You can probably build a proof of concept fairly easily, but you probably won't be able to build out a complete database yourself. But you might be able to use something like FreeDb to build a custom service of your own.

An example of a similar approach is explained in modest detail here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDDB

It's possible that newer CDs include some sort of distinct identifier, but I am not familiar with current CD industry standards.